# How to clean up crazy mesh?

Tags: mesh, optimization

I'm a novice at Blender.

I started using a program called 3d Slicer for medical images. It takes a medical scan (CT, MRI etc) and allows you to turn it into a 3d image (in this case .obj file for Procreate to read).

I'd like to get it to where I can paint on these objects in Procreate but if you look at my images, you'll see the problem.

This is my (admittedly weird) workflow:

Create the .obj file in 3d Slicer. Import it into Forger (a sculpting app) because Procreate won't take the file as-is, I have to follow some other instructions to fix the UV wrapping. Then I open it in procreate and get the mess you see in my last image when I try to paint. Without paint, it looks great!

So I imported it into Blender and tried limited dissolve (you'll see the results in the images) and then tried voxel remesh but it completely crashes with that.

Any advice on how to clean this up to take away that "can't paint on it cleanly" issue?

[image: 1]
[.obj when imported]

[image: 2]
[The mesh]

[image: 3]
[The mesh with x-ray view]

[image: 4]
[The mesh after applying limited dissolve]

[image: 5]
[The problem - when I try to paint over it in procreate.]

Comment: Please add your images directly into your question rather than make folks go to an external web site to view them! https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: After your limited dissolve - just to be sure, select the whole mesh and do a merge (M) by distance, then make sure the normals are pointed the right way (Shift+N).

Comment: Try the decimate modifier, I'm always surprised at how good a job it does

Comment: DOn't use Limited DIssolve, instead try the Quad remesh and also re-unwrap (with the Smart UV Project option for example)?

Comment: If Blender is already in the pipeline, why not use it to paint the object right away?
in my opinion, the painting problem may occur because of flipped normals. As mentioned by others, this can easily be fixed in Blender with a few keystrokes - go to edit mode, then `[shift + N]`

Comment: There seems even to be a syncing script to sync objects from Blender in 3D slicer

https://github.com/dentsoft-foundation/linkSlicerBlender
. Looks like a far better workflow to do your painting in Blender, just using these two applications for your workflow

Comment: Wow, I can't believe all the suggestions! I'm going to try them all, just to see what works best, thank you so much! I'll report back. You all are amazing! :D

Comment: @maddes8cht Unfortunately, that sync between Slicer and Blender is really for something more like dentistry - it's only for when the 3D model is already made and imported into Blender, then they can do a bunch of measuring functions in 3D Slicer and have it sync up. Not good for me. :( I was very excited about it though! I installed it but realized when I was trying to use it that it wasn't what I needed. But thank you!

Comment: @Psyonic I tried decimate and while it seemed to help the mesh to be a bit less cramped, it didn't fix the original painting on issue.

Comment: @Christopher Bennett after that, I also did a merge by distance and recalculate normals - still didn't fix the problem. :(  But thanks, you two! I'm happy to have things to try!

Comment: @maddes8cht I am embarrassed to say I didn't know you could really paint-paint in Blender. I know there's a texture paint but I haven't done much with it. Am I supposed to use the grease pencil stuff or does texture paint actually just paint color where I want? And can I do the things I want to do with the color (change blend modes, smudge, etc)? Thank you!

Comment: @moonboots I'm trying but so far Quad remesh has only succeeded in crashing Blender! lol I'll maybe decimate first then quad remesh? We'll see. Someone else on Reddit suggested the "Instant Meshes" add-on. I might try that, too. Thank you so much for your reply and suggestion!!

Comment: Yes try Instant Remesh, I don't know if it's available as an addon but it exists as a separate app.

Comment: @moonboots IT WORKED! Your first idea worked (The crash was because I was stupid about the voxel size, I messed it up).

Comment: @moonboots It won't let me edit to say THANK YOU!!

Comment: Do you mean that Quad remesh worked?

Comment: @moonboots Yes, quad remesh and then unwrapping with smart UV project. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the *Remesh > Quadriflow Remesh* tool, choose the desired number of faces, once done unwrap your object with the *Smart UV Project* option:

[image]